# How to wire a 12V DC fan to a Molex connection?

Tags: dc

I have a 12V DC fan with two wires (black and red). I want to solder it to a Molex 8981 connection (powered by an ATX power supply).

Here are the details for the connection:
[image: Molex 8981 connection][image: Molex 8981 specification]

I'm guessing the fan's positive red wire goes to the +12V yellow wire, but I'm not sure what to connect the black wire to.

Comment: It would be better to crimp the wires to appropriate pins and use the matching connector, instead of soldering.

Comment: Or, get a [matching header](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?mpart=0015244441&vendor=900) and solder the fan to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what the Molex connector is coming from, but I'm assuming it's an ATX supply of some sort.
Anyway, connect the red wire to the +12V yellow, and the black wire to either of the 2 black ground wires.